# Creating Dijit > Editor > Plugins

Tags: dojo

I have been googling this subject for hours. Does anyone have an examples of a custom plugin being deployed in Dijit's Editor. I'd be really interested to look at it because I have been following [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-master/) without much success and of the few examples that exist out there none of them come with working examples :(

*(I'm looking to create a pulldown menu like the one for font selection)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no difference between a custom plugin and a "builtin" plugin, so I suggest just looking at a small builtin example like [TabIndent](https://github.com/dojo/dijit/blob/master/_editor/plugins/TabIndent.js), and then move on to the [font selection](https://github.com/dojo/dijit/blob/master/_editor/plugins/FontChoice.js) itself.

Comment: both links are broken!